# regex replace single line c++ comments

Tags: regex, visual-studio, comments

I would like to insert doxygen comments into my project. I want to do this as automatic as possible, so I had the idea to use regex and the search and replace functionality. 
Example:

```
int var; //Explanation variable
```

into:

```
int var; /**< @brief Explanation variable */
```

As a bonus, I also don't want to delete my code intend.
I tried different things like 
 
Find: `.+;*// .+` (finds the relevant lines)
 
Replace: `.+;*/**< @brief .+ */`
 
Problem is, that it doesn't insert the original text, it inserts the regex as plain text and it deletes the code intend.
Is there a way to to this properly? I have read many different posts but I can't get it working.

Comment: Use capturing groups/backreferences: `(.+;\s*)//\s*(.+)` -> `$1/**< @brief $2 */`.

Comment: you will need to capture the original text in capture-groups, and use backreferences in the replacement. I don't know what tool you are using for these replaces and what regex engine that uses?

Comment: @Doqnach I am using VS2017 but I also can use Eclipse Luna or Notepad++. I will use whatever is needed.

Comment: @xMutzelx: Then C++ tags is irrelevant, I removed it.

Comment: Use @WiktorStribiżew 's regex, except capture less in the first group: `(.+;*)// *(.+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)s and [**backreferences**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html):

*Find what*: `(.+;\s*)//\s*([^\r\n]+)`
*Replace with*: `$1/**< @brief $2 */`

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%2b%3b%5cs*%29%2f%2f%5cs*%28%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%29&i=int+var%3b+%2f%2fExplanation+variable%0d%0aMore+text+here&r=%241%2f**%3c+%40brief+%242+*%2f).

**Details**:

- `(.+;\s*)` - Group 1 (its value is accessed with the `$1` numbered backreference from the replacement pattern): any one or more chars other than line break chars, `;` and then 0+ whitespaces
- `//` - a double `/`
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^\r\n]+)`  - Group 2 (its value is accessed with the `$2` numbered backreference from the replacement pattern): any 1+ chars other than newline (`\n`) and carriage return (`\r`) chars (as `.` matches a CR (`\r`) in .NET regex).

VS 2015 test:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works almost perfectly. Last problem is, that the ending */ is on a new line.

Comment: @xMutzelx: I guess the `(.+)` matches `\r` in your case - replace the last `(.+)` with `([^\r\n]+)`

Comment: Wow, it is working for you. In VS2017 it places the */ on a new line.

Comment: I saw your last comment to late, now it works fine. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it worked with `(.+)` because it was the last line in the text. Once I added a line below, I could repro the issue. The `.` matches any symbol but a newline in .NET regex. In Notepad++, you would not have this issue, you could use `(.+)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^(\s*[^;]+;\s*)\/\/(.*)$
```

and replace by this:

```
$1/**< @brief $2 */
```

[Regex101Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C6A18m/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, same problem like the answer above. The ending */ is in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the solution of @WiktorStribizew a bit, to make it even more comfortable:

Find: `(.+;[^\r\n]\s*)//\s*([^\r\n]+)`

I inserted `[^\r\n]` into the front, to avoid some special cases like:

```
int var;
//Comment for the next function
int function ()
```